# Maven and AnypointStudio

Tags: java, maven, mule

I have installed the Maven plugin, "Maven Integration for Eclipse" in Anypoint Studio. How should I test from within anypoint studio to confirm that my maven plugin installation is correct? The documentation says Windows--> Preferences-->AnypointStudio->    Maven Settings-->TestMavenConfigutation. However in my machine I don't have such an option, I only have a ''Maven' option separately and it dosen't have a 'TestMavenConfigutation' option. Another thing I noticed is that after the installation of the plugin I no longer see the 'Run As --> Mule Project' option from the file menu. I can still run as a mule project successfully from 'Run Configurations'. The green play button icon which is also 'Run As' shows the mule icon for the projects, but gives deployment error when run. I am just wondering if this is normal after installing the plugin. Hope someone can advise me on the above, thank you so much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, from the documentation  Windows--> Preferences-->AnypointStudio-> Maven Settings-->TestMavenConfigutation should look like below image

[maven test configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWOBR.png)

Here I am using Anypoint version 6.5.0 and need to install maven in your local and and set the path.

Check the below configurations:
1. Check your Anypoint studio version. (if it is anypoint studio >=7.0 i.e.,  Mule 4 then all applications are maven projects by default)
2. In local check maven version(mvn -version) to know maven has installed in your system or not.

Comment: Hi Zakira, thanks for the response. I am using anypoint studio version 5.4.0 and the mule 3. I saw your screen capture, thanks for that, but I really don't see a TestMavenConfiguration option in my set up. As for the checking of mvn, yes I have done that, my maven version is 3.6.0